# Unable to fetch inputs for Python script deployed on Flask

Tags: python, flask, web-deployment

Can someone help me with my code please. I'm trying to deploy a simple python script on Flask and facing the following issues.

1. The script isn't asking for any inputs from the user on website.
2. TypeError: The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
3. If I tweaked the code a bit, The script is returning only the initialized string variable("Hello! World)

My script is running absolutely fine on command shell and ipython notebook.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    name=request.args.get("name","")
    age=request.args.get("age","")
    gender=request.args.get("gender","")
    quote=Quote_generator(name, age, gender)
        
    return (
        """<form action="" method="get">
                <input type="text" value="name">
                <input type="number" value="age">
                <input type="text" value="gender">
                <input type="button" value="Go">
              </form>"""
            
        )

@app.route("/<name>/<age>/<gender>")
def Quote_generator(name, age, gender):
    string="Hello! World"
    try:
        if gender=="M":
            if age in range(1,21):
                string= name + ",  Life is like a box of chocolates. You never know what you're going to get"
            elif age in range(22, 31):
                string= name + ", If you want to live a happy life, tie it to a goal, not to people or things"
            elif age in range(32, 41):
                string= name + ", Be Kind, Have Grace, Give Thanks, Speak Love & Stage Swaggy"
            elif age in range(42, 51):
                string= name + ", Do not pray for easy lives, Pray to be stronger men"
            else:
                string= name + ", You are more than what you were"
            
            
        elif gender=="F":
            if age in range(1,21):
                string= name + ", I Like it when you smile, it's cute"
            elif age in range(22, 31):
                string= name + ", You can make anything by writing"
            elif age in range(32, 41):
                string= name + ", Choose to do more than just exist; choose to live"
            elif age in range(42, 51):
                string= name + ", In a gentle way, you can shake the world"
            else:
                string= name + ", It is never too late to begin exploring the world"
            
    except ValueError:
        string= name + ", Beauty begins the moment you decide to be Yourself"
    return string
    

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
    name=input("Your name: ")
    age=int(input("How old are you: "))
    gender=input("How do you identify yourself(M/F):").upper()
    print(Quote_generator(name, age, gender)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check you code, you didn't closed the bracket.
`print(Quote_generator(name, age, gender))`

Run your code with:

```
python3 filename.py
```

See the screenshot below its your code and its working. Please check it.

[image]